# How can I maintain a consistent count of entities with App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, transactions, google-cloud-datastore

### Simplified context:

I have this schema for storing users, their messages, and a count of how many unread messages they have.

```
from google.appengine.ext.ndb import *

class User(Model):
  unread_messages = IntegerProperty()

class Message(Model):
  read = BooleanProperty()
  user_id = IntegerProperty()
```

My goal is for `messages` to contain the correct value after a user has read some messages. When creating messages, it's easy to use a transaction to increase the unread_messages property by one and move on. But reading messages seems to be more difficult.

### Here's what I've tried:

#### 1. Updating the entity using only relative changes.

The problem is that the delta comes from a query, which could return the same results twice before a write is complete.

```
#User reads messages

query = Message.query()
query = query.filter(Message.read = False)
query = query.filter(Message.user_id = user.key.id())
unread_messages = query.fetch(10)

for message in unread_messages:
  message.read = True

put_multi(unread_messages)

txn(user.key.id(), -len(unread_messages))

@run_in_transaction
def txn(id, delta):
  user = Key(User, id).get()
  user.unread_messages += delta
  user.put()
```

#### 2. Running a count query after a put.

As far as I can tell, there's no way to execute code after a write is guaranteed to be visible in a query. So for this method, I just set a delay of a few seconds on the task. This works most of the time, but it's easy to see how a write that takes longer than my delay would result in an incorrect value.

```
query = Message.query()
query = query.filter(Message.read = False)
query = query.filter(Message.user_id = user.key.id())
unread_messages = query.fetch(10)

for message in unread_messages:
  message.read = True

put_multi(unread_messages)

taskqueue.add(url = '/tasks/update-unread-messages', params = {'user_id': user.key.id()}, countdown = 10)
```

Associated task:

```
query = Message.query()
query = query.filter(Message.read = False)
query = query.filter(Message.user_id = user.key.id())
count = query.count()
user.unread_messages = count
user.put()

@run_in_transaction
def txn(id, delta):
  user = Key(User, id).get()
  user.unread_messages += delta
  user.put()
```

### Here's what I've considered trying:

1. Giving a user's messages the same ancestor so I can do ancestor queries. This would be a last resort because of the performance constraints of ancestor queries, and the fact that I don't want to have to replace every entity.
2. Using the transactional flag with the taskqueue. For my put_multi to be transactional though, I would need to use an ancestor query.
3. Restructuring the schema in various ways, but it always comes back to being able to run code once I know a put is complete.

Comment: What performance constraint do you think there is on ancestor queries ?  The performance constraint is on the write throughput for a single entity group.

Comment: Given your Message entity only references a single User, I can see no reason for not using Ancestor's in the Key of the Message entity.

Comment: And why not use a cursor if you fetch 10 entries every time.

Comment: I would also choose a delayed count task after a put because the count is then self healing if an incorrect count ever occurs.  Furthermore you could initiate a mostly redundant re-count in response to user actions that indicate a special interest in the count being completely accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It feels expensive to update all the messages which will be read and update a counter. Why not use an entity with the keys of the unread messages to read multi fast (by key) and update only a single user entity, which has an index and count for all the unread messages.

```
class User(ndb.Model):
    unread_messages_count = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=0) 
    unread_messages_index = ndb.KeyProperty(repeated=True)
```

This unread message index will only work if the messages are read in the same order as they arrive. See comments below.

Comment: If there are a lot of messages this could be very expensive.  In addition an entity is limited to 1MB, thus putting a ceiling on the total number of unread messages.  Yes that is a lot of Key's.  But if you just want a count, fetching 1MB every time (ok yeah it could be in memcache) could be a bit expensive.

Comment: Tim. please explain: "if there are a lot of messages this could be very expensive."?? Instead of a single put multi to update the fetched messages, you only have to put a single entity with the keys. And ndb caching will help to optimimize this update.

Comment: The original question was to maintain an up to date count.  If he has 10000 unread messages then get() a 10000 * length of Key entity every time just to report on length of keys seems a bit excessive.  It does have an upside though- you have 10000 keys ready if you want to fetch some messages in key order.  But useless if you want to sort based on some other criteria.

Comment: Based on his original question it "feels" expensive to update the fetched messages. If the messages are not read in the order of the keys (message arrival) this unread message index will not work. If the unread message index holds thousands of unread messages per user, there is a lot to win. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Yes, if the stored order is the order presented then this could be a win.